# Are senators of The Galactic Republic democratically elected?

Tags: star-wars

The Galactic Republic certainly doesn't work like Earth's nations. It has senators who represent their systems which are governed by different laws (with little intervention from the Coruscant).

Is there a law of The Galactic Republic to enforce that all senators are elected democratically in their system? Or, are systems free to choose senators their own way (like even by Monarchy)?

Comment: It works like the UN (e.g. not very well).

Comment: Senators even on Earth aren't necessarily democratically elected. The Republic shares some notable similarities with the Roman Republic, and the [Roman Senate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Senate) was composed of a senator class determined by the worth of an individual's property.

Comment: @Null Whatever that is, at least that's same across the entire republic. That may not be the case of The Galactic Republic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/galactic-republic) (considered a fully canon source of information about the Star Wars Universe) has this to say about the Galactic Senate:

> **GALACTIC REPUBLIC**
>
> *For over a thousand years, the Galactic Republic stood firm as a democratic union that governed the galaxy. **The Republic was governed
>   by the Galactic Senate, consisting of elected officials from each
>   system and world,** and Jedi Knights served as peacekeepers. With the
>   rise of Supreme Chancellor Palpatine, however, the Galactic Republic
>   -- and democracy -- would crumble.*

Obviously in such a disparate galaxy there are bound to be exceptions but it appears that in the main, Senators were supposed to be democratically elected to represent their planetary systems.

Comment: Which sort of begs the question: who the hell voted for Jar Jar?

Comment: @phantom42 - I'm guessing a whole bunch of Gungans who'd never met him.

Comment: @phantom42 He was a reputed guy. Remember, when he went to a planet of force sensitives with Windu (Star Wars: The Clone Wars)..

Comment: @phantom42 - he was a war hero and a personal friend of fabled Jedi and of the former Queen. Hell, people voted for far less plausible reasons for US senate (wife of dead senator?)

Comment: @DVK Sure, but that doesn't mean he'd make a good politician. Anyone who's seen Jar Jar talk would have to wonder if he's got brain damage.

Comment: @phantom42 - that applies to most politicians.

Comment: @phantom42: You should see it from a Naboo’s perspective: once he’s elected as a senator, he will get sent *very far away*.

Comment: Does this section mean that each system **and** each inhabited world gets a representative?  Do the extremely wealthy that make their homes on remote worlds in remote systems with no other sapient species get two representatives?  Is there a representative from every government outpost world?  Why would species' (presumably highly populated) homeworlds have the same number of representatives as a planet with a few hundred?  Either this entry is oversimplifying to a fault, or this is the worst electoral system ever made.

Comment: @Namfuak - According to the old Databank website, highly populated systems would have their own representative. Sparsely populated systems would club together with other planets to sponsor a Senator for their region.

Comment: @Richard Fair enough, I can still see loopholes with that but no government is completely free of them.

Comment: @Namfuak: Weathy and populated systems only need 1 Senator. They can buy as many others as they need. >:-)

Comment: @Namfuak: you have to remember George Lucas is from California, and therefore well-used to losing out in terms of Senators-per-voter, via just such a system, to those pesky Rhode Islanders. Speculative fiction after all is just an exaggeration of the familiar ;-)